# C++ Template Base Class Design Choice

Tags: c++, oop, templates, polymorphism

I have a Template base class and I want to store the actual derived class into a collection polymorphically. The derived class have concrete template specialization. So I want to get rid of the template for my collection. Considering below snippet, is this possible or is there a better architecture?

Edit:
Thanks for the answers. My design goal is:

1. Enforce an execution policy for every derived class.
2. No additional storage involved.
3. It needs to be resolved at compile time since I have a finite known number of policies up front.
4. Flexible to change, e.g. adding new policies.

```
enum class Policy {
    SEQ,
    PAR
};

template <Policy>
class FibSolver {
    virtual void solve() = 0;
};

template <Policy p>
class DPFibSolver : FibSolver<p> {
    virtual void solve() final {}
};

template <Policy p>
class RecursionFibSolver : FibSolver<p> {
    virtual void solve() final {}
};

// is this possible?
FibSolver* solvers[] = {new DPFibSolver<Policy::SEQ>{}, new DPFibSolver<Policy::PAR>{},
                        new RecursionFibSolver<Policy::SEQ>{}, new RecursionFibSolver<Policy::PAR>{}};
```

Comment: Why is `FibSolver` a template at all?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Because I want to enforce all derived classes to have a policy and it needs to resort at compile time. Better ways?

Comment: If you want to enforce at compile time that the derived types have a policy, you need to select that policy at compile time too. You can have `FibSolver<Policy::SEQ> *seqSolvers[] ...` and another array for `PAR`.

Comment: Or, I guess,an array of `variant<FibSolver<SEQ>*,  FibSolver<PAR>*>`. It's not obvious how usable that is, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible, since `FibSolver` itself is not a type and you hence can't have an array of it or a pointer to it.

Templates are meant to produce actual, distinguishable types. So, I think you might not even actually *want* templates here - feels like a case for a `const Policy policy_type` member?

Anyway, if `FibSolver<...>` actually needs to be a template, just give it a parent class:

```cpp
class FibSolver_base {
    virtual void solve() = 0;
};

template <Policy>
class FibSolver : public FibSolver_base {
…
};
```

now you have a common parent type; `Fib_solver_base *solvers[] =…` would then work.

Again, using templates in this context seems to be a design mistake, but I don't know why you're doing it, you might have a good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A wrapper base was my original design. But I would like to enforce all derived classes to have a policy. This seems less expressive imho. I could use a const member but it needs additional runtime storage. Considering my updated goals, what's a better approach?

Comment: you require them to have a policy by having a policy field; making that part of the type seems disadvantegous.